# Cómo puedo pasar de un Login a un AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando pasar de mi MainActivity que es mi Login a una ventana que contiene una lista de distintos fragments, pero cuando ingreso mis datos en el Login y le doy al botón "Ingresar", la aplicación se cierra (android studio).

He intentado con estas dos formas y las dos me cierran la aplicación cuando doy al botón Ingresar... Ayúdenme por favor.

1.

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inicio.class);
                                startActivity(i);
```

2.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inicio.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText txtCor, txtPas;
Button btnIngresar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCor = findViewById(R.id.txtCor);
    txtPas = findViewById(R.id.txtPas);

    btnIngresar = findViewById(R.id.btnIngresar);

    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Thread tr=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String res=enviarPost(txtCor.getText().toString(), txtPas.getText().toString());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int r=objJSON(res);
                            if (r>0){
                                //Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inicio.class);
                                //startActivity(i);
                                Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Inicio.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            tr.start();

        }
    });

}

public String enviarPost(String cor, String pas) {
    String parametros = "cor=" + cor + "&pas=" + pas;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String respuesta = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.10/WebService/valida.php");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(parametros.getBytes().length));

        // con esto se indica que salen algunos datos (parametros)
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(parametros);
        wr.close();

        Scanner inSteam = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());

        while (inSteam.hasNextLine())
            respuesta += (inSteam.nextLine());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return respuesta.toString();
}

public int objJSON(String rspta) {
    int res = 0;
    try {
        JSONArray json=new JSONArray(rspta);
        if(json.length()>0)
            res=1;
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return res;
}
}
```

Ese es mi Login, el que intento vincular a mi (public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

Styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Este es todo el error que me da el Logcat cuando intento vincular el Login con un AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener:

> 02-23 23:50:23.361 32670-32670/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   02-23 23:50:24.412 32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken I/InstantRun:
>   starting instant run server: is main process 02-23 23:50:24.608
>   32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken W/art: Before Android 4.1, method
>   android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 02-23 23:50:24.830
>   32670-32714/com.example.matias.taken D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty
>   regions requested: true 02-23 23:50:24.836
>   32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken D/Atlas: Validating map... 02-23
>   23:50:24.928 32670-32714/com.example.matias.taken I/Adreno-EGL: : EGL
>   1.4 QUALCOMM build: () OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.01 Build Date: 01/29/15 Thu Local Branch: Remote Branch:
>   Local Patches: Reconstruct Branch: 02-23 23:50:24.929
>   32670-32714/com.example.matias.taken I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized
>   EGL, version 1.4 02-23 23:50:24.942
>   32670-32714/com.example.matias.taken D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug
>   mode 0 02-23 23:50:24.988 32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken
>   I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id:
>   android.os.BinderProxy@3a189687 time:308031486 02-23 23:50:28.981
>   32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken I/Timeline: Timeline:
>   Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3a189687 time:308035479 02-23
>   23:50:41.974 32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
>   02-23 23:50:45.228 32670-32670/com.example.matias.taken I/Timeline:
>   Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.matias.taken
>   time:308051726 02-23 23:50:45.842 32670-32670/? D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM 02-23 23:50:45.843 32670-32670/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.matias.taken, PID: 32670
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.matias.taken/co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice.Inicio}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead. at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an
>   action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead. at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
>   at co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:31)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5979) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)  02-23
>   23:50:45.848 32670-32670/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32670 SIG:
>   9

Comment: Podrías agregar la información que te arroja el LogCat?

Comment: 02-23 21:35:31.037 26970-26970/com.example.matias.taken E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.matias.taken, PID: 26970

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matias.taken/co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice.Inicio}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:201)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                              at co.quindio.sena.tutorialwebservice.Inicio.onCreate(Inicio.java:31)

Comment: Por favor trata de mejorar tu pregunta añadiendo la información del LogCat pero utilizando las herramientas de edición que provee StackOverflow. Para el código esta el simbolo "{}" y se podrá observar mejor esta sección al igual que esos errores que colocas en los comentarios de tu pregunta. Un Saludo!

Comment: Por favor trata de mejorar tu pregunta añadiendo la información del LogCat pero utilizando las herramientas de edición que provee StackOverflow. Para el código esta el simbolo "{}" y se podrá observar mejor esta sección al igual que esos errores que colocas en los comentarios de tu pregunta. Un Saludo!

Comment: Al igual agrega en tu pregunta el archivo de **style.xml**

Answer (score -1):

El error es el siguiente. Ve a tu archivo style.xml. Debes tener algo asi

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

El problema es que en tu nuevo acitivity estas intentando usar un toolbar (lo deduzco por el log del error) o algo que replaza el action bar. Por ende al usar un estilo que implementa por defecto un action bar, se da un conflicto que detiene la app.

Cambialo de la siguiente manera

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

De esta manera el conflicto se elimina. Espero que estoy te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias Jhon, pero aún así sigue el problema, deje los detalles del problema más arriba y el archivo style.xml con el archivo login para que puedas verlos y si puedes ayudarme sería genial. Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: El error estoy del logcat que pasas estoy muy seguro que es lo que te menciono. procura cambiar tooods todos los estilos que usas a aquellos que en su parent tegan un noActionBar. cmabialo y me muestras de nuevo como queda un styles.xml al momento de probar.